# Azure db update

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database

Sorry for perhaps noob question - is there a simple way of immediately update 
of Azure database? (For example the database contains the fields from model classes and some of this fields are gone while other (new fields) are appear - how to do update of Azure database easily in this case? )
Perhaps anyone could provide a link at some sample?

Comment: Something like [EF code first](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620.aspx)?

Comment: Yes, perhaps this is what I need. I will look at samples now

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [EF code first](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620.aspx)